# How to write List of lists in csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a list of lists and I want to write it in csv file
Example list:

```
data=[['serial', 'name', 'subject'],['1', 'atul','tpa'],['2', 'carl','CN'].......]
```

data[0] should be column names
everything else is row wise data

Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: actully I have multiple sheets in excel file and I parsed all the sheets and created a list of lists. So when I am writing it into csv file with your solution it's pasting column names for each and every sheet

Comment: `csv` is just writing out what you give it. Skip the first entry of every sheet but the first if you see duplicate column names.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is trivial with the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

You already have the header in `data` as the first row; you can write all rows in one go with the `writer.writerows()` method. That's all there is to it, really.

Comment: As seedubbs in their answer mentions, "TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function".

Comment: @samkhan13: you and they are using Python 2, not Python 3 (note the question tags). Use `open('output.csv', 'wb')` instead (so use binary mode so the CSV module can control what newlines are written).

Answer (score 2):

I get the following error when I include newline='': TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

This is what I used and worked fine for me.

```
csv_file = open("your_csv_file.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerows(clean_list)
```

Comment: That's because you are using *Python 2*, not Python 3, as tagged on the question.