# save to CSV a reorganized list

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of arrays that I would like to save it in a CSV file so that each array is a column and each value inside of the array is a raw. Thanks!

> [array([1.        , 0.98667283, 0.93550512, 0.9101134 , 0.86350843,
>          0.81362023, 0.79597313, 0.78630291, 0.76510444, 0.75112696,]), 
>      array([1.        , 0.93300358, 0.82632603, 0.75321894, 0.68761633,
>          0.62084654, 0.54310758, 0.5185884 , 0.50324798, 0.47731232,
>      array([1.        , 0.97515355, 0.8841753 , 0.76284806, 0.76663915,
>          0.733638  , 0.74516099, 0.70097266, 0.70757977, 0.70645296,])]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write List of lists in csv file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575456/how-to-write-list-of-lists-in-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: you can use  `np.savetxt("filename.csv", np.stack( your_list, axis=1 ), delimiter=",")`, by using numpy (`np`)

Comment: I get this error ..ValueError: all input arrays must have the same shape